# Будет ли число double представлено бинарно одинаково в одном и том же приложении, но на разных машинах?

Tags: оптимизация, компилятор, double, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Возьмём любой компилируемый язык программирования, где есть тип данных с плавающей точкой двойной точности размером 8 байт (обычно называющийся Double).

Если я напишу программу на таком языке, приравняю в ней числовую константу, например, `-987654321.01234`, и скомпилирую её в .EXE/.DLL, то будет ли двоичное представление содержимого этой переменной всегда равно соответственно `5B 94 81 58 34 6F CD C1` ?

Мой вопрос не о точности представления действительных чисел, и даже не о том, что компилятор обычно не даёт никаких гарантий о внутреннем формате плавающей точки.

**Я спрашиваю про уже скомпилированную программу, которая будет запущена на других компьютерах и операционных системах, на которых она сможет работать!**

Проще говоря, если в восьми байтах у меня лежит число `-9.8765432101234e+8` , то гарантируется ли, что младшие четыре байта в десятичном целочисленном представлении (signed 32-bit integer, little-endian) равны `1484887131`, а старшие четыре байта – `3251466036` ?

То, что на том же самом компьютере это верно – понятно. А вот на других, в том числе – на будущих процессорах? (Для определённости, можно не брать в расчёт «старые» модели типа Pentium III)

Если ответ окажется положительным (и чем-то подкреплённым), то вопрос можно расширить на интерпретируемые языки программирования – верно ли и для них? Более общий вопрос прозвучит так: будут ли одни и те же *вычисления* с плавающей точкой приводить к бинарно-эквивалентному результату, если они выполнены на разных машинах? (Но тут мне думается, что нет, потому что есть понятие «машинный эпсилон», которым определяется точность промежуточных округлений; если конечно он де-факто не одинаковый у всех…)

Comment: Изменение формата double означает изменение архитектуры процессора, а значит **скомпилированая** программа будет непригодна для этой изменённой архитектуры, и ОС скорее всего просто откажется её запускать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно будет одно и то же. С точностью до [endianness](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Формат записи `Double` описывается стандартом [IEEE 754](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]